# Load Error when trying to pass complicated function into Simpson's rule

Tags: julia, simpsons-rule

I have written a method that approximates a definite integral by the composite Simpson's rule.

```
#=
f  integrand
a  lower integration bound
b  upper integration bound
n  number of iterations or panels

h     step size
=#
function simpson(f::Function, a::Number, b::Number, n::Number)
   n % 2 == 0 || error("`n` must be even")
   h = (b - a) / n
   s = f(a) + f(b)
   s += 4*sum(f(a .+ collect(1:2:n) .* h))
   s += 2*sum(f(a .+ collect(2:2:n-1) .* h))
   return h/3 * s
end
```

For "simple" functions, like `e^(-x^2)`, the `simpson` function works.

```
Input: simpson(x -> simpson(x -> exp.(-x.^2), 0, 5, 100)
Output: 0.8862269254513949
```

However, for the more complicated function `f(x)`

```
gArgs(x) = (30 .+ x, 0)
f(x) = exp.(-x.^2) .* maximum(generator.(gArgs.(x)...)[1])
```

where `generator(θ, plotsol)` is a function that takes in a defect θ in percent and a boolean value `plotsol` (either 0 or 1) that determines whether the generator should be plotted, and returns a vector with the magnetization in certain points in the generator.

When I try to compute the integral by running the below code

```
gArgs(x) = (30 .+ x, 0)
f(x) = exp.(-x.^2) .* maximum(generator.(gArgs.(x)...)[1])
println(simpson(x -> f(x), 0, 5, 10))
```

I encounter the error `MethodError: no method matching generator(::Float64)`. With slight variants of the expression for `f(x)` I run into different errors like `DimensionMismatch("array could not be broadcast to match destination")` and `InexactError: Bool(33.75)`. In the end, I think the cause of the error boils down to that I cannot figure out how to properly enter an expression for the integrand `f(x)`. Could someone help me figure out how to enter `f(x)` correctly? Let me know if anything is unclear in my question.

Comment: You should probably add the exact signature of `generator`, and make sure that the actual error is not caused by that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an array `x` , `gArgs.(x)` returns an array of `Tuple`s and you are trying to broadcast over an array of tuples. But the behavior of broadcasting with tuples is a bit different. Tuples are not treated as a single element and they themselves broadcast.

```
julia> println.(gArgs.([0.5, 1.5, 2.5, 3.5, 4.5])...)
30.531.532.533.534.5
00000
```

This is not what you expected, is it?

You can also see the problem with the following example;

```
julia> (2, 5) .!= [(2, 5)]
2-element BitArray{1}:
 true
 true
```

I believe `f` is a function that actually takes a scalar and returns a scalar. Instead of making `f` work on arrays, you should leave the broadcasting to the caller. You are very likely to be better of implementing `f` element-wise. This is the more Julia way of doing things and will make your job much easier.

That said, I believe your implementation should work with the following modifications, *if you do not have an error in* `generator`.

```
function simpson(f::Function, a::Number, b::Number, n::Number)
   n % 2 == 0 || error("`n` must be even")
   h = (b - a) / n
   s = f(a) + f(b)
   s += 4*sum(f.(a .+ collect(1:2:n) .* h)) # broadcast `f`
   s += 2*sum(f.(a .+ collect(2:2:n-1) .* h)) # broadcast `f`
   return h/3 * s
end

# define `gArg` and `f` element-wise and `generator`, too.
gArgs(x) = (30 + x, 0) # get rid of broadcasting dot. Shouldn't `0` be `false`?
f(x) = exp(-x^2) * maximum(generator(gArgs(x)...)[1]) # get rid of broadcasting dots
println(simpson(f, 0, 5, 10)) # you can just write `f`
```

You should also define the `generator` function element-wise.